# Como mostrar os arquivos que necessitam ser comitados?

Tags: git

Como mostrar os arquivos que necessitam ser "comitados"?

Ou,tem algum programa, para distro baseado em Linux, que se comporte igual o modulo Git do Eclipse, que me mostre os arquivos que necessitam ser adicionados e "comitados"?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326086/112052

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O comando `git status` fornece diversas informações sobre os estado atual do repositório. Isso inclui quais  alterações estão na staging area (e serão inclusas no próximo commit), quais arquivos tem modificações no diretório atual mas fora da staging area e quais são os "desconhecidos" presentes no diretório mas ignorados pelo git.

Por exemplo:

```
~/D/web (master) $ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Main.hs
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Routes.hs
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser um meio de fazer isso utilizando um GUI, o [Git Force](https://sites.google.com/site/gitforcetool/home) é uma programa que funciona no Linux. O Stack Overflow em inglês também tem uma resposta que divulga várias alternativas para user no linux [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux). (a primeira resposta)