# Quais as diferenças entre os estados dos arquivos do Git (untracked, unmodified, modified, staged)?

Tags: git, terminologia

Gostaria de saber, quais as **características e diferenças** entre os estados dos arquivos **durante seu ciclo de vida** no *Git*.

**Estados**:

- *untracked*
- *unmodified*
- *modified*
- *staged*

[image: git]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Acho que podemos entender melhor estes estados criando um projeto do zero. Primeiro vou criar uma pasta chamada "projeto" e entrar nela:

```
$ mkdir projeto
$ cd projeto/
```

Por enquanto ela está vazia. Vou usar [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) para inicializá-la como um repositório Git:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/usuario/projeto/.git/
```

Agora vou começar meu projeto adicionando um arquivo (com o conteúdo "hello world" dentro dele), e em seguida verificar o status deste arquivo com [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status):

```
$ echo "hello world" > hello.txt

$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        hello.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Veja que o arquivo `hello.txt` está listado como "**Untracked** files". Ou seja, o Git não está "*trackeando*" este arquivo. Podemos dizer que o Git não está controlando o ciclo de vida deste arquivo (e confesso que não sei se "ciclo de vida" é o termo tecnicamente correto).

É como se o Git dissesse: *"Vi que que tem um arquivo aqui, mas eu não sou responsável por ele"*.

Para que o Git passe a ser responsável por este o arquivo, use [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

```
$ git add hello.txt

$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   hello.txt
```

Agora o arquivo está listado como "*Changes to be committed"*, ou seja, ele fará parte do próximo *commit*. Diz-se então que o arquivo está "**staged**" (ou está na *staging area*, ou no *index*, ou no *cache*, [*não sei pra que tantos nomes para a mesma coisa*](https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/2szztw/is_the_index_the_same_as_the_staging_area/)).

De qualquer forma, repare que há inclusive uma instrução para retirar o arquivo do *staging area* (*use "git rm --cached <file>..." to **unstage*** - nas versões mais novas do Git a mensagem é "*git restore --staged <file>... to unstage*").

Em vez de *unstagear* o arquivo, vamos *commitá-lo* <sup><sub>*(adoro esses estrangeirimos...)*</sub></sup>

```
$ git commit -m"Primeiro commit"
[master (root-commit) ccc2a05] Primeiro commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 hello.txt

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Após o *commit*, o `git status` diz que não há o que mostrar (*"nothing to commit, working tree clean"*), ou seja, todos os arquivos estão atualizados: o seu conteúdo bate com o último *commit*, não houve nenhuma alteração). Pode-se dizer então que o arquivo `hello.txt` está **unmodified** (não há modificações, se comparado com o último *commit*).

Então vamos alterar o arquivo, adicionando algum texto ao seu final:

```
$ echo "Novo texto" >> hello.txt

$ cat hello.txt
hello world
Novo texto
```

Agora o arquivo tem 2 linhas, vamos ver o que o `git status` mostra:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   hello.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Ele mostra que o arquivo está **modified**, ou seja, foi modificado, se comparado ao último *commit*. Mas repare que esta modificação não estará no próximo *commit*, pois o arquivo está listado como *"Changes not staged for commit"* e no final ainda aparece a mensagem *"no changes added to commit"*.

Eu posso ver as modificações usando [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/hello.txt b/hello.txt
index 3b18e51..7d34649 100644
--- a/hello.txt
+++ b/hello.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 hello world
+Novo texto
```

O trecho `+Novo texto` indica que esta linha foi adicionada (`+`). Para a alteração ficar disponível no próximo *commit*, basta usar `git add`:

```
$ git add hello.txt

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   hello.txt
```

Repare que o arquivo continua com status "*modified*" (afinal, ele está diferente do último *commit*), mas agora estará no próximo *commit* (*"Changes to be committed"*).

Ou seja, ele está ao mesmo tempo **modified** (diferente se comparado ao último *commit*) e **staged** (pois está na *staging area*).

O fato de estar na *staging area* faz com que `git diff` não mostre mais as diferenças:

```
$ git diff
(não mostra nada)
```

Para saber o que mudou, deve-se usar a opção `--cached`, que compara o *staging area* (também chamado de *cache*) com o último *commit*:

```
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/hello.txt b/hello.txt
index 3b18e51..7d34649 100644
--- a/hello.txt
+++ b/hello.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 hello world
+Novo texto
```

A propósito, [`--cached` é equivalente a `--staged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--cached--merge-baseltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203) - ou seja, compara os arquivos que estão *staged* com o último *commit*.

---

Resumindo:

- *untracked*: o git não sabe nada a respeito do arquivo. Quer dizer, até sabe que ele existe, mas não vai controlar seu ciclo de vida
- *staged*: os que estão no *staging area/index/cache*. São os que estarão no próximo *commit*
- *modified*: os que foram alterados, se comparados ao último *commit*
- *unmodified*: os que não foram alterados

Por fim, vale lembrar que a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) diz que na verdade só existem dois estados: *tracked* e *untracked*. Ou seja, ou o Git está controlando o ciclo de vida do seu arquivo (*tracked*) ou não está (*untracked*). Sendo que um arquivo no estado *tracked* pode estar *staged*, *modified* ou *unmodified*.

Comment: Muito bom! Excelente! 

Comment: @rbz Obrigado! Esqueci de comentar que usei git 2.11.0 para windows, então pode ser que algumas mensagens sejam diferentes em outras versões (não tenho certeza). Mas a ideia é a mesma, independente disso.

Answer (score 12):

1. **Untracked** é o estado onde o arquivo ainda não foi 'rastreado'.
2. **Unmodified** é o estado onde o arquivo não sofreu alterações em relação a sua referência.
3. **Modified** é o estado onde o arquivo sofreu alterações em relação a sua referência.
4. **Staged** é o estado onde o arquivo já foi endereçado e aguarda ser transferido ao repositório.

Observe [neste link](http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html) que comandos são utilizados em cada etapa do processo até que o arquivo seja adicionado ao repositório. Acredito que ajudará no entendimento.

No mais, seguem links de boas referências: [Git - Book](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) | [Git - Guia Prático](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html)

Comment: Caio, a `staged`, o que seria o "endereçado"? Seria tipo "marcado para envio"?

Comment: Seria algo semelhante a isso. O Stage pode ser visto como uma área temporária na qual o arquivo permanece até que não seja enviado ao repositório. Irei adicionar mais um link a resposta, ok?